# Allow project run on master only in teamcity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm setting up teamcity and I have 2 Projects using the same VCS root, Build and Deploy.

Is there a way I can:

- Trigger the build project on all branches except master
- Trigger the deploy project only on master

I have it set to automatically trigger but both projects still show pending changes and a user can still manually run deploy on any branch they wish.

Build Trigger Branch filter:
`+:*`
`-:<default>`

Deploy Trigger Branch filter:
`+:<default>`
`-:*`

Do I need to configure the VCS root twice with different branch specifications?

Please let me know if I need anything else.

Thanks for your help.
Kurtis

Comment: is it correct that you want to deploy master, but not trigger to build master?

Comment: Yeah. So the deploy project builds, test and packages up the project. The build project just builds and tests. Thanks

Comment: what is the reason to build branches if they will not be deployed?

Comment: I want other branches to build and run test so we have a place to immediately see if a branch is safe to merge into master. 
I've used GitLab CI before and in the merge request, if the build fails for that branch, you wouldn't be able to merge it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, you can't.

But you have to do the follows:

- Delete ability to run `Build` and `Deploy` configuration from users.
- Set trigger `+:*; -:<default>`  for a `Build`

I hope the Deploy has dependencies from a Build.

- create the new Deploy configuration, let's say `Deploy only master`
- Add snapshot dependency from `Deploy`
- define hidden variable `reverse.dep.*.teamcity.build.branch` with value `<default>`

So, nobody cannot run Build, and Deploy. If someone runs `Deploy only master` and select another branch it will not work because you will replace the `teamcity.build.branch` to  master

Comment: I see, the above sounds like I will get what I want but I'm just unsure on how to define a hidden variable.? Thanks for your help thought!

Comment: To add specification to a build parameter, click the Edit button in the Spec area when editing/adding a build parameter. Display: If hidden is specified, the parameter will not be shown in the Run Custom Build dialog, but will be sent to a build; if prompt is specified, TeamCity will always require a review of the parameter value when clicking the Run button (won't require the parameter if build is triggered automatically); if normal is selected, the parameter will be shown as usual.